# Materials UI DataGrid throwing js errors and not displaying data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I'm trying to do a basic implementation of the DataGrid from materials UI. I am copying their examples but I keep getting these JS errors

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'modifiers' of type 'array' supplied to 'ForwardRef(Popper)', expected 'object'

Material-UI: The key `selectLabel` provided to the classes prop is not implemented in ForwardRef(TablePagination).
You can only override one of the following: root,toolbar,spacer,caption,selectRoot,select,selectIcon,input,menuItem,actions.
```

Here is the code I have

```
import React from 'react';
import { DataGrid, GridRowsProp, GridColDef } from '@material-ui/data-grid';

function BudgetDataGrid() {
   const rows: GridRowsProp = [
    { id: 1, col1: 'Hello', col2: 'World' },
    { id: 2, col1: 'XGrid', col2: 'is Awesome' },
    { id: 3, col1: 'Material-UI', col2: 'is Amazing' },
  ];

    const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    { field: 'col1', headerName: 'Column 1', width: 150 },
    { field: 'col2', headerName: 'Column 2', width: 150 },
  ];
  
      return (
        <DataGrid columns={columns} rows = {rows} /> 
      );
    
}

export default BudgetDataGrid;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While annoying, those are really warnings but for some reason they love to use `console.error()` vs `console.warn()`.

PropTypes is for type checking and is used inside of one of their components.  They're forwarding props but sending the wrong type of data.  Its their bug.  You should probably read about prop-types. https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

As for the `select-label` error, it's sending over a key for that but it's not able to be overwritten.  Again, their bug.